# INTERSHOP HTTP Service not getting Started

Tags: intershop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQe3X.png)I have installed 7.9 on my local and everything goes well except the fact that INTERSHOP HTTP Services are not getting started for me.

Please suggest what to do.
I am using port 82 and it is not being used anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Please.. A little more information would be helpful to get a useful answer to your question. What do the logs in `server/local/webadapter/log` say?

Comment: Does it start from the command line? You can start with with a command like this: d:\...\build\server\local\httpd\bin\httpd.exe -f d:\...\build\server\local\httpd\conf\httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Try re-entering your os user password by right click > properties > log on. Sometime it fails because the os user isnt allowed to run services. Other than that you'll need to post the logs for more clues.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your system password, this might happen.
Try changing the login in the services and restarting the system.
If that is not the case, then more investigation is required, like log files.